# Nest with_filetree and loop

Tags: ansible

How can I nest with_filetree and a loop?

Here is my attempt using a block:

```yaml
- name: Deploy
  hosts: all
  connection: ssh
  become: true

  vars:
    instances:
      abcd:
        admin_port: 12345
  
  tasks:
    - name: Template cfg
      vars:
        file_path: "{{ item.path }}"
      block:
        - name: Templating config files
          vars:
            instance: "{{ item.value }}"
          template:
            src: "config-templates/{{ file_path }}"
            dest: "{{ install_dir }}/{{ instance.name }}/"
          loop: "{{ instances | dict2items }}"
      with_filetree: "config-templates"
      when: item.state == 'file'
```

But ansible complains:

> `ERROR! 'with_filetree' is not a valid attribute for a Block`

I must be missing something obvious, but I don't see how to do this. It does not seem to work using with_nested/with_cartesian.

Please help.

Comment: You cannot loop over a block. You actually can't really nest loops in ansible appart looping on an include file. This might be the solution here. Warning: you have to use `loop_control: {loop_var: someothervar}` to discriminate the inner and outer loop variables or they will collide on the same `item`.

Comment: @Zeitounator Thanks for showing me a way to do it. Not sure if what you referred to was `include_tasks`, but it works the way you described.

Comment: I meant exactly that. Meanwhile, after some short sleep, I was able to test another (I believe...) working solution with a single task. See my answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using include to nest loops is the only viable solution when you have several loops in the include task.

Meanwhile on most scenario including yours, you can reduce the work to a single loop. The basic idea: rather than nesting loops, you create a list with all elements to loop over. In this case, the [`product` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#product-filters) should do the job.

The other "trick" (since there are no real examples in the doc for `filetree`...) is to remember that a `with_<some_lookup>` loop can generally be transformed to `loop: {{ lookup|query('some_lookup', args....) }}`.

Putting it all together, here is a (not fully tested) example that should meet your requirement:

```yaml
- name: Templating from filetree and instances
  vars:
    file: "{{ item.0 }}"
    instance: "{{ item.1.value }}"
  template:
    src: "config-templates/{{ file.path }}"
    dest: "{{ install_dir }}/{{ instance.name }}/"
  loop: "{{ lookup('filetree', 'templates/config') | product(instances | dict2items) | list }}"
  when: file.state == 'file'
```

---

**Edit**: not trying to push towards "MY !!!" solution :), but if you don't have too many tasks, here is a possible scenario to keep everything in the same file.

**Edit2**: You actually don't even need a task, especially if your play targets several hosts. Updated with a full example pseudo playbook.

```yaml
- name: Deploy
  hosts: all
  connection: ssh
  become: true

  vars:
    my_files: "{{ lookup('filetree', 'templates/config') | selectattr('state', 'eq', 'file') | list }}"
    action1_list: ['some', 'list']
    action2_list: ['other', 'list']
    
  tasks:
    - name: action 1
      debug:
        msg: action1
      vars:
        file: item.0
        action1_item: item.1
      loop: "{{ my_files | product(action1_list) | list }}"

    - name: action 2
      debug:
        msg: action2
      vars:
        file: item.0
        action2_item: item.1
      loop: "{{ my_files | product(action2_list) | list }}"
```

Comment: You are awesome! Unfortunately in reality I have multiple tasks that I want to run inside the outer loop over instances, some with_filetree, some just simple non-looped tasks. So I guess I'm stuck with include_tasks and an extra file. But as this answers my question as it is, I will accept, if nothing shows up that is simpler and/or works with multiple tasks.

Comment: See my edit for a possible solution. The choice is yours ;)

Comment: You deserve another upvote - I wish I could. But this looks like it will end up as the accepted answer :) I will try to apply this to my scenario later.

Comment: Made the solution even more sexy ;)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Zeitounator's comment, I was able to create a solution. Is has a drawback, however, in that the inner loop task(s) need to be put in a separate file.

```yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Template cfg
      include_tasks: inner-template-tasks.yaml
      with_filetree: "templates/config"
      when: item.state == 'file'
```

inner-template-tasks.yaml would look something like this:

```yaml
- name: Templating {{ item.path }}
  vars:
    instance: "{{ loop_item.value }}"
  template:
    src: "config-templates/{{ item.path }}"
    dest: "{{ install_dir }}/{{ instance.name }}/"
  loop: "{{ instances | dict2items }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: loop_item
```

I only wonder why ansible forces us to use a separate file for this...