# Nested templating with folders and files

Tags: ansible

There is a variable which contains a name with value `foo`. Only for this name 'special' templating must be done. The folder name, the filename and content must be templated 2 times, and once without any additions. The remaining files must also be templated, but without the special treatment. Let me describe my issue:

This is my variable:

```
bar:
  - name: something
  - name: foo
```

This is my template directory in Ansible:

```yaml
templates/foo/another_folder/foo.spec
templates/foo/folder_folder/folder2/some_file/foo.service
templates/foo/some_file.txt
templates/something/ignore.txt
```

The contents of `foo.spec`:

```yaml
name: foo
```

The goal to have the directory structure on the target machine:

```yaml
foo/another_folder/foo.spec
foo/folder_folder/folder2/some_file/foo.service
foo/some_file.txt

foo-1/another_folder/foo-1.spec
foo-1/folder_folder/folder2/some_file/foo-1.service
foo-1/some_file.txt

foo-2/another_folder/foo-2.spec
foo-2/folder_folder/folder2/some_file/foo-2.service
foo-2/some_file.txt

something/ignore.txt
```

The content for each `foo.spec` should be templated to:

```
# for foo:
name: foo
--
# for foo-1
name: foo-1
--
# for foo-2
name: foo-2
```

To solve my problem, I took a look at a similar question, which is [with_filetree and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62805492/nest-with-filetree-and-loop). However, I simply can't figure out where to start. Is this possible to configure in Ansible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is quite an awkward requirement but was kind of fun crafting a solution so here we go.

The below solution takes for granted your templates have the exact same file names as the target files where you deploy them. If you ever want to add the `j2` extension to them, see the [examples in the `filetree` documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/filetree_lookup.html#examples) to remove it while templating to target.

It is not possible in ansible to imbricate loops in the same task. The solution to this is to loop over an `include_tasks` and add more loops in the included file.

The basic operation is to template an entire file tree to a target dir so this will be our final included file. In between we just have to detect if we are in the `foo` situation where we want to loop X time over a range of integers, or in the default one where we only process the directory once.

I used the exact same file tree you introduced in your question for my tests. The only change is the content of the `foo/another_folder/foo.spec` which is now:

```
name: {{ spec_name }}
```

Let's start with the base playbook `deploy.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: my bizare templating pattern
  hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: false

  vars:
    bar:
      - name: something
      - name: foo

    target_base_dir: /tmp/example/

  tasks:
    - name: make sure target base dir exists
      file:
        path: "{{ target_base_dir }}"
        state: directory

    - name: load template pattern chooser file
      include_tasks: "template_pattern_chooser.yml"
      loop: "{{ bar }}"
      loop_control:
        loop_var: template_pattern
```

This is the included `template_pattern_chooser.yml`

```yaml
---
- name: Select the corresponding templating pattern
  vars:
    find_me:
      - "pattern_{{ template_pattern.name }}.yml"
      - "pattern_default.yml"
  include_tasks: "{{ lookup('first_found', find_me) }}"
```

As you can see, this will look for either a specific file named after the template pattern name or fallback to a default one.

Thi is the specific `pattern_foo.yml`. Note that this is where set the var `spec_name` which is used in the above template.

```yaml
---
- name: "loop over our {{ template_pattern.name }} pattern"
  vars:
    target_dir_name: "{{ template_pattern.name }}-{{ pattern_iteration }}"
    spec_name: "{{ target_dir_name }}"
  include_tasks: "template_tree.yml"
  loop: "{{ range(1,4) | list }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: pattern_iteration
```

`pattern_default.yml`:

```yaml
---
- name: default templating pattern
  vars:
    target_dir_name: "{{ template_pattern.name }}"
  include_tasks: template_tree.yml
```

Note that both files include the same `template_tree.yml` file. The only change is that we loop over it when we are dealing with the `foo` pattern. This is where the real job takes place:

```yaml
---
- name: Get list of templates only once
  set_fact:
    template_tree: "{{ query('filetree', 'templates/' ~ template_pattern.name ~ '/') }}"

- name: Create needed target dir
  file:
    path: "{{ target_base_dir }}/{{ target_dir_name }}"
    state: "directory"

- name: Create needed directories inside target
  file:
    path: "{{ target_base_dir }}/{{ target_dir_name }}/{{ item.path }}"
    state: "{{ item.state }}"
  loop: "{{ template_tree }}"
  when: item.state == 'directory'

- name: Deploy templates
  template:
    src: "{{ item.src }}"
    dest: "{{ target_base_dir }}/{{ target_dir_name }}/{{ item.path }}"
  loop: "{{ template_tree }}"
  when: item.state == 'file'
```

Running this as a test on my machine gives:

```
$ ansible-playbook deploy.yml 

PLAY [my bizare templating pattern] *****************************************************************************

TASK [make sure target base dir exists] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [load template pattern chooser file] *****************************************************************************
included: /home/user/test/template_pattern_chooser.yml for localhost => (item={'name': 'something'})
included: /home/user/test/template_pattern_chooser.yml for localhost => (item={'name': 'foo'})

TASK [Select the corresponding templating pattern] *****************************************************************************
included: /home/user/test/pattern_default.yml for localhost

TASK [default templating pattern] *****************************************************************************
included: /home/user/test/template_tree.yml for localhost

TASK [Get list of templates only once] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create needed target dir] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Create needed directories inside target] *****************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/something/', 'path': 'ignore.txt', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/something/ignore.txt', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 6, 'mtime': 1640280116.3296282, 'ctime': 1640280116.3296282}) 

TASK [Deploy templates] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/something/', 'path': 'ignore.txt', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/something/ignore.txt', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 6, 'mtime': 1640280116.3296282, 'ctime': 1640280116.3296282})

TASK [Select the corresponding templating pattern] *****************************************************************************
included: /home/user/test/pattern_foo.yml for localhost

TASK [loop over our foo pattern] *****************************************************************************
included: /home/user/test/template_tree.yml for localhost => (item=1)
included: /home/user/test/template_tree.yml for localhost => (item=2)
included: /home/user/test/template_tree.yml for localhost => (item=3)

TASK [Get list of templates only once] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create needed target dir] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Create needed directories inside target] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280024.0969715, 'ctime': 1640280024.0969715})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640279254.875486, 'ctime': 1640279254.875486})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'some_file.txt', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/some_file.txt', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280116.3376281, 'ctime': 1640280116.3376281}) 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280051.5691671, 'ctime': 1640280051.5691671})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280051.561167, 'ctime': 1640280051.561167}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder/foo.spec', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/another_folder/foo.spec', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 21, 'mtime': 1640279254.871486, 'ctime': 1640279254.871486}) 

TASK [Deploy templates] *****************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280024.0969715, 'ctime': 1640280024.0969715}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640279254.875486, 'ctime': 1640279254.875486}) 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'some_file.txt', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/some_file.txt', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280116.3376281, 'ctime': 1640280116.3376281})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280051.5691671, 'ctime': 1640280051.5691671}) 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280051.561167, 'ctime': 1640280051.561167})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder/foo.spec', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/another_folder/foo.spec', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 21, 'mtime': 1640279254.871486, 'ctime': 1640279254.871486})

TASK [Get list of templates only once] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create needed target dir] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Create needed directories inside target] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280024.0969715, 'ctime': 1640280024.0969715})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640279254.875486, 'ctime': 1640279254.875486})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'some_file.txt', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/some_file.txt', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280116.3376281, 'ctime': 1640280116.3376281}) 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280051.5691671, 'ctime': 1640280051.5691671})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280051.561167, 'ctime': 1640280051.561167}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder/foo.spec', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/another_folder/foo.spec', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 21, 'mtime': 1640279254.871486, 'ctime': 1640279254.871486}) 

TASK [Deploy templates] *****************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280024.0969715, 'ctime': 1640280024.0969715}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640279254.875486, 'ctime': 1640279254.875486}) 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'some_file.txt', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/some_file.txt', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280116.3376281, 'ctime': 1640280116.3376281})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280051.5691671, 'ctime': 1640280051.5691671}) 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280051.561167, 'ctime': 1640280051.561167})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder/foo.spec', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/another_folder/foo.spec', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 21, 'mtime': 1640279254.871486, 'ctime': 1640279254.871486})

TASK [Get list of templates only once] *****************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Create needed target dir] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Create needed directories inside target] *****************************************************************************
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280024.0969715, 'ctime': 1640280024.0969715})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640279254.875486, 'ctime': 1640279254.875486})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'some_file.txt', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/some_file.txt', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280116.3376281, 'ctime': 1640280116.3376281}) 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280051.5691671, 'ctime': 1640280051.5691671})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280051.561167, 'ctime': 1640280051.561167}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder/foo.spec', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/another_folder/foo.spec', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 21, 'mtime': 1640279254.871486, 'ctime': 1640279254.871486}) 

TASK [Deploy templates] *****************************************************************************
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280024.0969715, 'ctime': 1640280024.0969715}) 
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640279254.875486, 'ctime': 1640279254.875486}) 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'some_file.txt', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/some_file.txt', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280116.3376281, 'ctime': 1640280116.3376281})
skipping: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file', 'state': 'directory', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0755', 'size': 3, 'mtime': 1640280051.5691671, 'ctime': 1640280051.5691671}) 
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/folder_folder/some_file/foo.service', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 4, 'mtime': 1640280051.561167, 'ctime': 1640280051.561167})
changed: [localhost] => (item={'root': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/', 'path': 'another_folder/foo.spec', 'state': 'file', 'src': '/home/user/test/templates/foo/another_folder/foo.spec', 'uid': 1000, 'gid': 100, 'owner': 'user', 'group': 'users', 'mode': '0644', 'size': 21, 'mtime': 1640279254.871486, 'ctime': 1640279254.871486})

PLAY RECAP *****************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=24   changed=12   unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=1    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

This is the result in the target dir:

```
$ tree /tmp/example/
/tmp/example/
├── foo-1
│   ├── another_folder
│   │   └── foo.spec
│   ├── folder_folder
│   │   └── some_file
│   │       └── foo.service
│   └── some_file.txt
├── foo-2
│   ├── another_folder
│   │   └── foo.spec
│   ├── folder_folder
│   │   └── some_file
│   │       └── foo.service
│   └── some_file.txt
├── foo-3
│   ├── another_folder
│   │   └── foo.spec
│   ├── folder_folder
│   │   └── some_file
│   │       └── foo.service
│   └── some_file.txt
└── something
    └── ignore.txt

13 directories, 10 files
```

And as an example the content of one the `foo.spec` files:

```
$ cat /tmp/example/foo-2/another_folder/foo.spec 
name: foo-2
```

Comment: I totally agree that this is a weird requirement, but looks really fun to craft! Glad you liked it. I like the answer as well. However, in my question, the folder foo-1 should be named foo. And to name the folder, you use {{ range(1,4) | list }}. In my use case, this should actually be a string, e.g. '-something', '-else'. But I can figure that out myself. Thnks.

Comment: I stuck to the exact requirement you gave in your question for the result folder structure. I can't guess what you don't describe.

Comment: I meant, you name them: foo-1, foo-2, foo-3. It should've been: foo, foo-1, foo-2.

Comment: I know, I'm asking the impossible, haha. But the foo.service files should've been named 'foo-1.service' and so on.

Comment: Unless you do something specific for each file you template (hence drop the use of `filetree` or do some really nasty outside mapping with a dirty dict) I don't see how to do that nicely.

Comment: I can live with doing something specific for each file.

Comment: Well then simply template each file separately because I don't see the point to try to make this generic in that case. My 2 cent: make sure you are actually not stuck in an [X/Y problem](https://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: You're totally right. I'm thinking to solve this problem in either Python or go with a total different approach. Thanks for all your work.

Comment: The 'actual' issue I'm having was I want my solution to be DRY, instead of templating 5 different files, I only wanted to do 1, and I wanted it to scale. However, I see that what I desire requires a certain technical solution that is 'too much'.